# javascript function parameter strange behavior ** WHAT's THIS

Tags: javascript

```
function updateView(campusId) {

        var latlng = CampusModel[campusId].latlng;

        var canvas = "campus-map";

        var zoom = 12;

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', mapInitialize(latlng, canvas, zoom));

...
}
```

I initially posted a picture showing that when function exe, campusId parameter sat to 1.

Once within the function block, [campusId] comes as undefined.

Anyone sees issue here?

CampusModel is defined.

Full code lines:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>MVC Example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script>

    /* MODEL */
    var CampusModel = {
        1:  {
                name: 'a Campus',
                address: 'somewhere',
                lating: { lat: 41.1693913, lng: -127.8672693 }
            },
        2:  {
                name: 'b Campus',
                address: 'somewhere2',
                lating: { lat: 19.2833298, lng: -124.1152499 }
            },
    };

    /* CONTROLLER */
    function initView() {
        var selector = document.getElementById('campuses-dropdown');
        var options = '<option>[ Select a Campus ]</option>';
        for (var campusId in CampusModel) {
            options += '<option value="' + campusId + '">';
            options += CampusModel[campusId].name;
            options += '</option>';
        }
        selector.innerHTML = options;
        selector.onchange = function() { updateView(this.value); };
    }

    </script>

    <script>
    //Helper functions

    // Initialize google map.
    function mapInitialize(latlng, canvas, zoom){

        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById(canvas);

        var options = {
          center: latlng,
          zoom: zoom,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var campusMap = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, options);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: campusMap,
            title: 'BCIT'
        });


        }

    function updateView(campusId) {

        var latlng = CampusModel[campusId].latlng;

        var canvas = "campus-map";

        var zoom = 12;

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', mapInitialize(latlng, canvas, zoom));

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() { 

            var center = campusMap.getCenter();
            google.maps.event.trigger(campusMap, "resize");
            campusMap.setCenter(center); 

            });

    }

    </script>

</head>

<body onload="initView()">

    <!-- VIEW -->
    <div>
        <select id="campuses-dropdown"></select>
    </div>
    <div id="campus-map">

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**selector.onchange = function() { updateView(this.value); };**

where does 'this' refer to in the original code? I thought it was pointing the selector. but maybe not?

still this.value passes the correct parameter to the function.

what's the underlying reasons

Comment: it depends where you're passing the campusId when you are actually calling the function...

Comment: What matters is how you're calling "updateView()". Also, that maps API call looks highly suspect to me - what does `mapInitialize()` do? You're calling the function there, so unless that returns the function to be used as the callback, that as written won't work.

Comment: Can you show us the code that calls updateView?

Comment: please refer to http://postimg.org/image/vv3bbtlq3/

Comment: @J.Doe that image does not show the code everybody is asking to see. Post the code where "updateView" is called. And post the code **here** - don't post a screenshot somewhere else with a link to it.

Comment: the picture contains variables window at the bottom left and shows campusId sat to 1.

Comment: @J.Doe that's deceptive - what you can do is put a `console.log(this.value)`  in that "onchange" handler to see what's really being passed.

Comment: Could you tell me why its deceptive?

Comment: console.log(this.value) shows correct numbers (1 or 2)

Comment: @J.Doe well maybe "deceptive" wasn't the best word; what I meant was that while the debug console may not be lying, you have to be careful how you interpret what it says and be aware of the assumptions you're making about how values in the debug view are actually flowing around in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've defined the function with `campusId` as a parameter, the value inside the function will be `undefined` unless you actually **pass** some value when the function is called.

*edit* — now that you've posted all of the code, it's immediately obvious what the problem is. You're binding that "updateView" function as an event handler, and expecting (incorrectly) that `this` will refer to the "selector" object when it is invoked.  What you need is a solution like you get with `.bind()`:

```
    selector.onchange = function() { updateView(this.value); }.bind(selector);
```

Comment: as you can see parameter is inserted when function called. but within the block it instantly becomes undefined.

Comment: @J.Doe ?? I most definitely cannot see. You need to post the code that **calls** the "updateView" function.

Comment: well, variable sub-window at the bottom left shows campusId sat to 1 right?

Comment: hm. What does 'this' refer to from the initial code? window? because when I console.log(this.value) without binding it, it still shows the correct option value.

Comment: @J.Doe yes sorry, that was an errror; I've updated that and I think it should be `.bind(selector)` instead of `.bind(this)`